# How to use unallocated space of disks beyond 2TB on Windows with MBR

Tags: windows, partitioning

Is there a way to use unallocated space of larger-than-2TB disks on Windows 7 without converting the disk to GPT? Why I cannot convert to GPT, because my system doesn't support UEFI boots, and I cannot install another drive to boot and use this disk as secondary storage.

The reason I'm asking about this is because it technically is possible, with a 3rd party software or driver. Windows 7 **is** capable of using this space if it's installed as a second/non-boot hard drive and configured as GPT. So there's no hardware limitation. The only problem seems to be is storing the partition information of the extended space on MBR which technically inst't possible because of 2TB limit. What I'm looking for is a software/driver that stores this information on somewhere else on the disk (e.g. a file) and makes this space available after Windows starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partition by itself cannot be larger than 2TB on MBR, but Windows is capable of addressing the data beyond. If you do the following, you might have access to it:

- install the system as you would normally, this is limited to 2TB. Make sure you still have room for an additional primary partition.
- now use a disk hex editor or a partition editor that lets you edit the single fields, and create another primary partition that starts at FFFFFFFF (4294967295) and has a size of your disk’s capacity (in sectors) minus 4294967295.
- In windows disk management, format this partition to your liking.

This works even in Windows XP, but is somewhat hackish. You can address up to 4TB this way.

Comment: If it works this way, hackish or not I think it would awesome :)